# Control Footer info via admin page - Python Django

Tags: python, html, django, postgresql

Django newbie here so apologies if this is a dumb question.

I am trying to create way to control the footer information via Admin page. Such as facebook, twitter links I have created a Footer model in models.py and migrated it and it is visible in the admin page. However when I add the footer information to the html into an a href it is not bing visible.

```
def register(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}! You may now login!')
        return redirect('login')
else:
    form = UserRegisterForm()
context = {
    "footer": Footer.objects.all(),
    'form': form
}
return render(request, 'member/register.html', context)





    <a href={{ footer.register.facebook }} class="pl-0 pr-3"><span class="icon-facebook"></span> </a>
                            <a href="#"class="pl-3 pr-3"><span class="icon-twitter"></span>{{ footer.twitter }}</a>
                            <a href="#" class="pl-3 pr-3"><span class="icon-instagram"></span>{{ footer.instagam }}</a>
                            <a href="#" class="pl-3 pr-3"><span class="icon-linkedin"></span></a>   




class Footer(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
description = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
contact_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
facebook = models.URLField(max_length=50, blank=True)
twitter = models.URLField(max_length=50, blank=True)
instagram = models.URLField(max_length=50, blank=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=30, blank=True)
footer_data = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.name} Footer'
```

Thanks all,
Onur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Footer.objects.all()
```

It will return a query set, not a single object. loop footer query set in template:

```
{% for f in footer %}
  <a href="{{ f.facebook }}" class="pl-0 pr-3"><span class="icon-facebook"></span> </a>
  <a href="#"class="pl-3 pr-3"><span class="icon-twitter"></span>{{ f.twitter }}</a>
  <a href="#" class="pl-3 pr-3"><span class="icon-instagram"></span>{{ f.instagam }}</a>
  <a href="#" class="pl-3 pr-3"><span class="icon-linkedin"></span></a>  
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Still getting the page not found error :( even though it is saved as https://www.facebook.com

Comment: edited answer:  {{ f.register.facebook }} should be in quotes and also theres no model called register its just "{{ f.facebook }}"